# Function on pandas columns in series

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, if-statement

I am looking to preform a function on a set of columns The table setup is as follows:

| Column_A | Column_B | Column_C | Column_D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 456 | null | null |
| 258 | null | 456 | null |
| null | 785 | null | null |
| null | null | 794 | null |

I am essentially looking to preform an operation (for the purpose of this example lets say I am trying to subtract 10 from the value) in order of "importance" of the column and store that in Column_D. For example:

- If Column_A is not null, then Column_D = Column_A - 10.
- If Column_A is null, then Column_D = Column_B - 10.
- If Column_B is null, then Column_D = Column_C - 10.

Column_B and Column_C should never both be populated, it is one or the other, but they can be populated simultaneously with Column_A. This dataset is absurdly large, so iterating through the rows is not a possibility. Does anyone have any suggestions?

So far I have tried if/elif/else logic, but that doesn't apply the values to the whole dataframe in my case. Maybe I am doing it incorrectly, I will try whatever solutions people have, even if it is an if/elif/else statement.

I am planning on trying the following after the code finishes:

```py
df.Column_D = df.Column_A.combinefirst(df.Column_B)

df['Column_E'] = df.Column_A.combinefirst(df.Column_C)

df.Column_D = df.Column_D.fillna(df.Column_E)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of bfill which fills the missing values based on the sequence that you specified. See below as example:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"Column_A": [123, 258, np.NaN, np.NaN],"Column_B": [456,np.NaN,785,np.NaN],"Column_C": [np.NaN,456,np.NaN,794]})
>>> df['column_D'] = df[['Column_A', 'Column_B', 'Column_C']].bfill(axis=1).iloc[:, 0] - 10
>>> df
   Column_A  Column_B  Column_C  column_D
0     123.0     456.0       NaN     113.0
1     258.0       NaN     456.0     248.0
2       NaN     785.0       NaN     775.0
3       NaN       NaN     794.0     784.0
```